# How to write a test function for salesforce ConnectApi.FeedElement

Tags: salesforce, apex

this is my code

```
public class ChatterFunction{

public ChatterFunction(){
    LIST<ISSUE__C> issID = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ISSUE__C];
    for(ISSUE__C i : issID){
        postfeed(i.Id);
    }
}

public static void postfeed(String iss){
      ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
      ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
      ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
      ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

      messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();


      mentionSegmentInput.id = '00528045147FTed';
      messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

      textSegmentInput.text = 'Something';
      messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

      feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
      feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;

      feedItemInput.subjectId = iss;

      ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null,feedItemInput );
}
```

}

and I tried to test it with code

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true) public static void testpostfeed() {
System.assertEquals(postfeed('a000l0013315hgr'),null);
}
```

but it shows the error message: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: postfeed(String)

I have no idea why it doesn't exist ....

Answer (score 0):

Your method is static so you need to call it like this

```
System.assertEquals(ChatterFunction.postfeed('...'), null);
```